# How should you preprocess the data before K-fold validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, preprocessing

I often see Kaggle notebook authors preprocessing the entire training data prior to splitting it for K-fold validation, but does this have a risk of leaking information into the validation set each fold? With regular train-validation split you only perform the preprocessing, whether by using scikit-learn's scalers or otherwise, on the training portion. On the other hand, the training portion is rotated in cross-validation, so does this choice of preprocessing the training data affect the end result meaningfully?